I have an/the impression that libraries are cool and comfortable

I have an impression that libraries are cool and comfortable.
(source)

Is an correct?
I don't know why an is possible. I would use "the" instead.

Either "an impression" or "the impression" are idiomatic in this context. They infer slightly different things, and "the" impression is far more common.
"I have an impression" implies a general or vague feeling or understanding, often without full certainty. It suggests that your perception is subjective or incomplete. "An impression" means there could be other impressions, or views of it.
"I have the impression" sounds more definite and specific, suggesting that the impression is a more solid or widely understood notion. The definite article suggests that this is the only real impression one could have, given what you know.

Thank you, Astralbee. I now think that my parsing of the sentence may be incorrect. Perhaps, "an <impression that ...>" rather than " + <that ...>".
